# Using an iMac as external monitor for my mid 2009 13'' MacBook Pro

Tags: macbook-pro, imac, display

Here's my MacBook:
http://www.everymac.com/systems/apple/macbook_pro/specs/macbook-pro-core-2-duo-2.53-aluminum-13-mid-2009-sd-firewire-800-unibody-specs.html

Here's the iMac:
http://www.everymac.com/systems/apple/imac/specs/imac-core-i5-3.2-27-inch-aluminum-late-2012-specs.html

Basically, my MBP has one Mini DisplayPort and the iMac has multiple thunderbolt ports. These two are the same shape.

Is there an adapter or chord I can use to connect these two so that my MacBook uses the iMac as a secondary monitor?

Comment: You want to subordinate your 2012 iMac to a 2009 MBP just for the screen space. Really?!  Surely you can just sync the filespaces or some better option?

Comment: Please don't be so rude, friend. For various reasons, yes, I do want that. The MBP is my main work computer for the moment and the iMac belongs to the school I go to. I have software and other things on my MBP that I can't get on the iMac unfortunately. So in those cases it would be hella convenient to just hook up my own computer to the iMac.

Comment: OK that makes sense. No, not rude—sanity checking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, you can't run Target Display Mode from Mini DisplayPort to Thunderbolt; only like to like or Thunderbolt to Mini-DP.

See http://support.apple.com/kb/PH14264

*Edit 2022*
Many years later, we now have a canonical QA for Target Display Mode. Please refer to  - [What are the requirements to use iMac screen as a second monitor - Target Display Mode?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/389348/what-are-the-requirements-to-use-imac-screen-as-a-second-monitor-target-displa)

Comment: Thanks for the link! From that article:
**"If you have a 27-inch iMac with a Mini DisplayPort, any other Mac with a Mini DisplayPort or Thunderbolt port can use it as a display. *Make sure you have a Mini DisplayPort to Mini DisplayPort cable."***

Would that work, do you think?

Comment: From that article, not if the iMac has Thunderbolt, **only** if it has DisplayPort.

Comment: To be honest, [I'm not so convinced](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3924#4). I'll probably buy a cable, try it myself and report back. Thanks for helping, though! You've pointed me in the right direction.

Comment: That table reinforces my existing perception.

Comment: After a second look, you may be correct. I'll give it a shot though.

Comment: Bought the cable and tried it out. You were of course correct, it did not work. Thanks for the help though!

Answer (score 0):

Screen-sharing may work for you in this instance, if the computers share a network.  Note this is not a hardware (cable) solution, but it may work sufficiently well for you.

From the iMac's Finder, locate and click on the MBP's icon from the left window pane.  In the title bar of the right pane, click on "Share screen...", authenticate, and begin your work.